# Smart Contract Idea

Tags: smart-contract

I wanted to know how one can submit ideas but not in a public domain but the idea is already in the question so it doesn't matter.

So the question is: If I wanted to submit ideas how would I go about it? I understand about NDAs and solicited ideas to companies, so is there a smart contract that can be written to allow the submission of ideas to make it simple and allow the company to pay the creator of the idea? If this could be done I guarantee that it would open the flood gates to ideas coming in.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, welcome to the community - please ask a concrete question in the question field.

Example: Where can I submit smart contract ideas publicly?

Answer (score 3):

Cardano StackExchange is a good place to ask technical questions, but I would suggest to visit Cardano Forums or Reddit to discuss ideas.

Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas can be aired afaik through Project Catalyst. There is also a Catalyst chat group on Instagram I think

You can get link from Daedalus site.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this would legally work. The first person to post an idea with a smart contract would not be the legal owner of the idea, thus a company would not be legally required to pay for it.

In other words, just because someone had an idea in 1990 and posted it somewhere, if someone else never saw it but came up with it themselves in 2020, they wouldn't have to pay a dime to the guy from 1990.